# Dynamically edit/add menu item - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change menu label of items accordingly if a user is logged in or not .
If user is not logged in i want to show Login and if user is admin I want to show Admin page and if normal user is logged in i want to show My Profile page .

I have tried this code.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'dynamic_label_change', 10, 2 );

function dynamic_label_change( $items, $args ) 
{ 
       if (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'topbar_navigation')
          { 
             $items = str_replace("Login", "Profile", $items);
          } 
      return $items;

}
```

Comment: So how did that code work? And can you articulate precisely what your question is?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new menu item then below code will help.

```
      // Add Login / Logout menu item dynamically to primary navigation menu
      function custom_menu_links( $items, $args ) {
          if ($args->theme_location == 'primary'){
             if (is_user_logged_in()) {
                 $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url(home_url()) .'">Logout</a></li>';
               } else {
                 $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Login</a></li>';
            }
       }

      return $items;
   }

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'custom_menu_links', 10, 2 );
```